# C# RSA Encrypt Private Decrypt Public?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, rsa

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.  Let's say I was releasing some web software built on ASP.NET MVC and I only wanted the end user to be able to add X users to the system.  The software would be hosted on their servers.

I want to include an encrypted file that when the user tries to add a new user, it goes out and reads from the file an encrypted string.  When the website decodes it, the clear text will be the number of allowed users.

What is the best/simplest way on my end to encrypt to generate this string on my end then decode it back to clear text in my application?  Obviously I want to ensure that the end user cannot be spinning up their own encrypted string and just replace mine.  I don't want to worry about having to try and obfuscate my source so that they would not be able to see how I decode the string.

Is it possible to encrypt with a private rsa key, then decrypt it with the public one?  I haven't had luck with that in the code below:

```
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        var pubicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
        var privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);

        var test = "this string needs to be encrypted then decrypted";

        var rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa2.FromXmlString(privateKey);

        var encryptedBytes = rsa2.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test), false);
        var encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);

        var rsa3 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa3.FromXmlString(pubicKey);

        encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);

        var decryptedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rsa3.Decrypt(encryptedBytes,                        false));
```

Comment: The software is running on their servers. If "they" are determined enough to peek into your source to determine how the license file is decoded, it'd be trivial for them to change your decoding function to return whatever they want.

Comment: Right... well as I said below.  Is it not possible to encrypt something with a private key, then only have the encrypted string be able to be decrypted with its brother public key?  The public key would live on their server, and they would never get access to the private key.

Comment: Please let us know where the keys are hosted.  I gather you mean that the public key is hosted at your client and the private key is hosted by you?

Comment: Greglev - Yes, The public key would live on their server.  I would think the public key would then be used to decrypt the string that was encrypted with the private key.  So that ONLY that specific public key would be able to decrypt the string.  Is this not the case?

Comment: Please look at what I submitted as an answer, which addresses your last comment as well.  In short, it is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a signature strategy, where the private key is used to generate a signature that verifies that your message is authentic.

```
// Create message and signature on your end
string message = "Here is the license message";

var converter = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] plainText = converter.GetBytes(secret);

var rsaWrite = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var privateParams = rsaWrite.ExportParameters(true);

// Generate the public key / these can be sent to the user.
var publicParams = rsaWrite.ExportParameters(false);

byte[] signature =
    rsaWrite.SignData(plainText, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());

// Verify from the user's side. Note that only the public parameters
// are needed.
var rsaRead = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsaRead.ImportParameters(publicParams);
if (rsaRead.VerifyData(plainText,
                       new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(),
                       signature))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Verified!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("NOT verified!");
}
```

This example was largely copied from Microsoft's site:

- [RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData Method (Byte[], Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tsc5d0z%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

And here is web page that explains the concept:

- [Using RSA for Signing Messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/09/19/761726.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is digital signature. It doesn't matter if the content is encrypted or not, since the user has the (public) key to decrypt it. All that matters is if the content's source is you. 
Since you have a config file I reckon it is XML, so you are looking for [XMLDSIG](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/).

You can easily achieve this using the [SignedXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class in .Net. Then all you need to do is verify the signature when loading the config file. This method allows you to eaisly use any X509 certificates you may have. You can even embed the public key in the signed file, so the user does not need to install your cert (public key).

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct, but I wonder about unforeseen consequences.

You state they will be running software on their servers, so this means they are hosting a service for themselves. But you also mention this service has to connect out tot he internet to add a user by validating with your server. What happens when the internet goes down or they want to have a secure system and a firewall blocks internet access to the servers? Will they completely lose their ability to function?

Just giving you a question to ask yourself  :p

Comment: Right.  If he keeps the current model, he'll need to have some kind of cache that will work for a period of time, allowing internet service to be restored.

Comment: No there will be no "reaching out" to our servers to validate against a web service, or anything to that affect.  What I thought would make sense is that if for the given installation, i generated a unique public/private key, if I encrypted the data with the private key, then ONLY its brother public key would be able to decrypt that string.  Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a public key to 'decrypt' the file. you can only decrypt the file with the private key.

In your case you could store the number of users as well a signature of the data which you create with your private key.

On the clients sever, you use your public key to verify the signature matches the data in the file (number of users)

However, it is possible that an advanced user could swap out your public key with their own and sign the file themselves.

Comment: So, as you say, is this really any more secure than just encrypting?  There is nothing preventing anyone from just creating their own public key and signature?  There is no fool proof way of preventing someone from doing this?

Comment: decrypting data and signing data is different. my point was that you cannot decrypt a message with a public key (op: Is it possible to encrypt with a private rsa key, then decrypt it with the public one?) you can not extract the plain text message from a signature. A signature, along with the plain text message and a trusted public key verifies that massage came from the holder of the private key.

Comment: Good clarification Stephen.  I deleted my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your comment in the question, your approach is using a key from a client and a key from yourself.  This will not work, as the prime numbers used in RSA are meant for use with only the corresponding private/public key.

What you need to do use your two keys and nothing from the client or the client's two keys and nothing of yours. For example,

1. You could *sign* it using your two keys by encrypting with your private key and allowing the client to decrypt using your public key.
2. You could encrypt it using your client's public key and have them decrypt is using their (the client's) private key.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Greg - Thanks for your help...I would think that both encrypting and decrypting using the public key would not be an option, though.  If that were the case, they could just write a program to encrypt the string themselves using the public key that is sitting right there on their server.  Then just replace my encrypted string.  Am I wrong in that thought?

Comment: I don't think the words are exactly correct, buy you're thoughts are correct.  I think you might have meant encrypting and decrypting using their keys would not be an option?  You're correct in thinking they could just change it at will.  I was describing the two approaches.

Comment: You'll want to use the 1st option, so that only you can create the data and sign it using your private key, having the client decrypt (verify signature) using your public key.

Comment: Greg, this makes sense.  But what is preventing them from spinning up there own signature and public key and swapping mine out.  Seems like just about as easy to circumvent?

Comment: Correct, they can do that and easily with .NET, whether you obfuscate it or not.  Just to be clear, what I mean is they can recompile your code and replace the key information, but at that point they would probably just remove anything like that.